# How can I repair a power supply for a Apple's Power Mac G4?

Tags: mac, power-supply, power, atx

This is an attempt to gather a **reference** page for anyone trying to replace a failing PSU from a Power Mac G4 with an equivalent **ATX** in the future.

There are still a couple of pages -*luckily*- available today (eg [1](http://www.smps.us/power-connectors.html) or [2](http://atxg4.com/gige-da.html)) and some [references materials](https://sites.google.com/site/jonathanrenaudg/ATX2G4.zip), but I'd like to have a canonical clear answer here on superuser, esp. since Apple removed from their website pin assignments information on most older models.

For instance, if one look at reference #2, there are a couple of clarifications needed for the Gigabit PowerMac:

1. The author suggests a pair of 3a diodes to be used for wiring up a +5v trickle (purpose: maintain memory during sleep) into a 12V line that provides operating power. This does not make much sense, maybe he meant for the atx 5v trickle to patch into the mac 12v pin position, but his diode diagram says into the g4 TRICKLE POWER position (only thing on the mac side with the word TRICKLE in it is the 28v trickle pinin... 5 and 12 into a 28v pin position.
2. The author gives pinout numbers for all the rewiring of a psu harness, but neglects to outright SAY to go ATX pinout 9 (5v) to Mac pinin 22.

So how would one replace a failing G4 PSU with a standard [ATX 1.x or ATX 2.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) ? The answer should be using a *ATX 20-pin to 24-pin adapter [cable](http://www.smps.us/20-to-24pin-atx.html)* for clarity. The answer does not need to adress the issue with Cinema Display (original G4 PSU have an extra line of 25V for the display that regular power supplies don't). Finally there should be -*ideally*- an answer for **each** models:

1. Yikes/Sawtooth
2. Gigabit/DigitalAudio
3. Quicksilver
4. Mirror Drive Door

[image: ATX/G4 Pins color scheme]

Comment: [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Power+Mac+G4+Quicksilver+Power+Supply+Replacement/2053) have a good guide on removal of the PSU which also mentions the different pin layout. They don't go into detail on converting ATX to work (I assume they are just replacing it with another PowerMac PSU).

Comment: I found [this blog](http://www.applefritter.com/?q=node/23857) article. Unfortunately I don't have a G4 in order to test the theory.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to use diodes to feed the mac's trickle power from 5V and 12V. Apple only made it 28V because some accessories connected to the ADC or Firewire ports need that much. The computer's trickle powered internal components only need 5V when the computer is off or sleeping, and only 12V when it's running. So if you're not using any devices which take power from ADC or Firewire, then this solution works fine.